# If technetium has three stable isotopes, what does this mean for other elements

Tags: physics

If technetium has three stable isotopes in a universe pretty much identical to ours, doesn't this mean that the weak nuclear force is different as well? How would a weak nuclear force allowing three stable technetium isotopes affect other elements?

Comment: What qualify as stable and what are those "stable" isotopes of technetium look like?

Comment: I'm not sure what they would look like, however they don't emit radiation.

Comment: So you want to modify island of stability? Tough one ;D

Comment: yep, seems like it.

Comment: I can't post an answer, because changes would be so extreamly drammatic, that I do not have enough qualification for that. Playing with universe constants is very dangerous game.Fo sake of worldbuilding this isotopes better be some "magical" unobtanium and/or handwaveium

Comment: Why 3 stable isotopes? The closest any odd number element comes to that is Potassium in which K40 has a 1.3e9 year half life. The other odd atomic number elements all have 0, 1 ,or 2 stable isotopes. This is related to isotopes having greater binding energy if the proton or neutrons can pair up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to fight a huge amount of physical (and possibly chemical) laws here if you reduce (or nullify) weak interaction to get stable isotopes of radioactive elements. My knowledge about nuclear physics is rather limited, but whole bunches of galactic evolution depend heavily on the weak forces. Especially the existence of stars is strongly connected to it, as it relies on nuclear fusion by fusing two protons to deuterium. Without weak interactions, that doesn't work as one of these protons has to be changed to a neutron.
There is an [abstract](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.74.035006) ([freely accessible version on Arxiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0604027)), written by Ron Harnik (Stanford University), Graham Kribs (University of Oregon) and Gilad Perez (University of California) which treats a universe without weak interaction which is still habitable and even if they got the mechanics of chemistry and nuclear physics nearly unchanged, they had to adjust a lot of physical constants to get there (that is as far as I am able to understand what they wrote XD). For better understanding, an example of what they had to adjust:

> (…) Our sun works through fusing two protons to deuterium, which proceeds through weak interactions. In the weakless universe of Harnik, Kribs, & Perez this is overcome by ensuring a high primordial deuterium to hydrogen ratio during Big Bang Nucleosynthesis (BBN). This permits long-lived stars fueled by direct deuterium-proton burning to helium, which proceeds through strong interactions. The high initial deuterium/hydrogen ratio (~1:3 by mass) is arranged by simply reducing the overall baryon to photon ratio, which allows the BBN deuterium to be produced at a lower temperature(…)

And that work is for the 'easy' case that the weak force is just not existent (what would make all isotopes of Technetium stable). Change it a way that only three are stable is **much** more complicated. I know this is not an exact answer to your question but an explanation why I think your question is not really answerable.

Answer (score 1):

### Short Version : A minor plausible "hand wave" for one stable isotope, but not three.

In what follows $Z$ is the atomic number - the number of protons in a nucleus.

Technetium ($Z=43$) and Promethium ($Z=61$) are rather odd in the sense that every element from $Z=1$ to $Z=82$ has at least one stable isotope, except those two elements.  While I doubt anyone could model this (easily) it's possible that the effects that make some Technetium isotopes unstable may be more subtle and might not need much of  a tweak to create at least one stable isotope.

You can see the unusual nature of this on [this chart of elements by stability from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_elements_by_stability_of_isotopes#/media/File:Periodic_Table_Radioactivity.svg).  They're like islands in sea of calm.

So ...

> If technetium has three stable isotopes in a universe pretty much identical to ours, doesn't this mean that the weak nuclear force is different as well ?

Three stable isotopes would probably not be possible without major changes in some of all of the forces.  Getting one isotope stable might be achievable without completely altering the rest of the nuclear properties of the elements.  You could probably at least keep at least one stable isotope as it is now (although the details would change).

Nuclei are not simple systems and the best term for them is "chaotic".  Very, very slight changes can have complex effects in chaotic systems.  There was a Physics SE question related to this : [Why is Technetium Unstable ?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/40960/why-is-technetium-unstable).  I would summarize the answers as "the theory doesn't resolve to that level of detail".  The difference between "decay possible" and "decay impossible" is a very small energy level by nuclear standards, so really very small tweaks would wipe these out.

You could certainly get away with this small handwave for most fiction purposes I think.

For the purposes of life, biochemistry and keeping things more or less like out universe for chemistry you are probably safe enough handwaving the small change.  Don't change the electromagnetic forces and you should be fine in that sense.

> How would a weak nuclear force allowing three stable technetium isotopes affect other elements?

I suspect it would drastically alter the all nuclear structures to the extent that you could not even be sure of e.g. a stable Carbon isotope.  This amount of change is not predictable at all - I would not even guess this.  Aiming for more than one stable isotope of Technetium is not practical, IMO, unless you just want to make up en entirely different universe with nothing at all the same or even similar.

The reasons one or at most two stable isotopes is a possibility with a slight tweak of our universe would be that two real isotope has a relatively long half life (about 4 millions years).  That's pretty long by the standards of unstable nuclei.  One isotope has a half life that's about 200,000 years which is not so good and would be a tougher "tweak" to make stable.  The other known isotopes are days or hours and would require a complete rewrite of nuclear processes to "fix".

But getting one stable would likely be a lot easier than trying to get two.  Two is a stretch while trying to keep everything else more or less the same.  Still, you could sell this if you really want to, but pushing it to three would be drawing attention to the problem, I think.

I don't think a stable Technetium isotope or two would alarm anyone or break any significant nuclear chains we can't loose.

There are no models that would let you make these calculations easily - no convenient formulae to relate these things.

Comment: Well, oof. I didn’t really want to handwave these stable isotopes but simultaneously wanted to know the knock on effects of there being three stable Isotopes. I’m probably just going to have to hand wave this then.

Comment: @JeffereyDawson Why do you want three stable isotopes, BTW ?  One is enough for your world to have e.g. Technetium ores and so on.